# How do browsers store JavaScript timers?

Tags: javascript, web, browser

Browsers throttle timers when the webpage moves to the background tab.

Wouldn't this require the browser to keep track of all the timers for a particular tab?

If so, and at a high level, how is this implemented?

Or, perhaps, is the browser able to throttle the activity of an entire tab without regards to any individual timer?

**Specifically:** Developers often keep track of timer ids for various reasons. Isn't this redundant in some cases? Hypothetically, couldn't the developer just invoke a function that tells the browser "when you reach a timer in the event loop, do something special"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Browsers throttle timers when the webpage moves to the background tab.**

The browser doesn't throttle timers in the background specifically. Each browser has an event loop that process' jobs in a queue. When an event completes, it pulls the next item from the queue and process' it (this differs across browsers). The event loop is throttled when the browser enters the background or a tab is not active. Every browser, again, implements this differently and will throttle / dethrottle differently.

As for javascript timers, they are also processed in the event loop, as is the resulting callback. This actually means that timers in javascript are never 100% accurate. If you set a timeout for 5000 milliseconds, it is highly likely that by the time the event loop gets round to processing the timeout/interval there will have been a few milliseconds delay, also when the callback function is queued the delay will add up to however long it takes the event loop to process it. Your 5000ms is more likely to have a few ms added to it in real time.

**Wouldn't this require the browser to keep track of all the timers for a particular tab?**

Yes, it would, however the execution is only as fast as the event loop will allow for jobs to be processed.

**Or, perhaps, is the browser able to throttle the activity of an entire tab without regards to any individual timer?**

No, the timers are subject to the event loop as much as any other code.

**To sum up...**

If the event loop is throttled it won't get through the queue as fast, therefore anything in the loop will complete slower than usual, including timers.

**Developers often keep track of timer ids for various reasons. Isn't this redundant in some cases? Hypothetically, couldn't the developer just invoke a function that tells the browser "when you reach a timer in the event loop, do something special"**

Yes it could be redundant in some cases, I often reference my timeouts or return them from functions but never do anything with the reference, at least its there should I need to do something with it in the future.

I'm not sure I understand you 100% on the second part to this. The developer DOES do something special when you reach a timer in the event loop, specifically your callback is executed at some point after the delay has ended. Other than that, you have no control over the loop itself other than queuing up your code to execute.

Comment: Developers often keep track of timer ids for various reasons. Isn't this redundant in some cases? Hypothetically, couldn't the developer just invoke a function that tells the browser "when you reach a timer in the event loop, do something special".

Comment: The event loop is hidden from us as developers, we don't need to go near it or interfere with it. Keeping track of timers in a running script can be beneficial, specifically if you use setTimeout over setInterval to manage cases that need interval behaviour but only for x number of iterations.

Comment: The misunderstanding is likely our definition of special. I meant special as something that currently is not done. As a simple example, `turnBrowserBlue()` could be a function that, when invoked, sets a listener that turns the browser blue whenever a timer is reached in the event loop in addition to the callback.

Comment: Oh I see, as far as I am aware you have no direct access to place a listener on the event loop for a specific action. This is more likely to be by design as interference with the event loop on a client could be considered a security hole.